# React siblings components communication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have an upload file component, delete file component and files table component(presents the existing files in the system using axios) in the same page:

**filesPage.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import UploadFile from '../components/UploadFile'
import DeleteFile from '../components/DeleteFile'
import FilesTable from '../components/FilesTable'

function UploadFiles() {
    return (
        <div className="filesPage">
            <UploadFile/>
            <DeleteFile/>
            <FilesTable/>
        </div>
    )
}
export default UploadFiles;
```

Now I want every time I upload new file or delete one, the files table will be updated which means after the axios post/delete, I need to rerender the files table component and do axios get again to get the active files.
Someone can help?

**FilesTable.js**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TablePagination from '@material-ui/core/TablePagination';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import axios from 'axios';
function FilesTable() {
    const [tfaArray, setTfaArray] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("api/tfa").then((res) => setTfaArray(res.data)).catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }, [])
    
    const columns = [ 
        {id: 'fileId', label: '#', minWidth: 100},
        {id: 'name', label: 'name', minWidth: 100},
        {id: 'date', label: 'upload date', minWidth: 100}
    ];
          
    const rows = tfaArray.map((tfa, index) =>  ({fileId: (index + 1), name: tfa.fileName, date: tfa.dateTime.slice(0,24)}) )
      
    const useStyles = makeStyles({
        root: {
          width: '50%',
          position: 'absolute',
          right: '10%',
          top: '15%',
        },
        container: {
          maxHeight: 322
        },

        headerCell: {
            background: '#F5F5F5',
            fontSize: '16px',
            zIndex: '0'
        }
      });
      
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
    const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(5);

    const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
        setPage(newPage);
    };

    const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event) => {
        setRowsPerPage(+event.target.value);
        setPage(0);
    };

    return (
        <>
        <Paper className={classes.root}>
            <TableContainer className={classes.container}>
                <Table stickyHeader aria-label="sticky table">
                    <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                        {columns.map((column) => (
                            <TableCell className={classes.headerCell}
                            key={column.id}
                            style={{ minWidth: column.minWidth }}>
                            {column.label}
                            </TableCell>
                        ))}
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableHead>
                    <TableBody>
                        {rows.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage).map((row, index) => {
                        return (
                            <TableRow hover role="checkbox" tabIndex={-1} key={index}>
                            {columns.map((column) => {
                                const value = row[column.id];
                                return (
                                <TableCell key={column.id}>
                                    {value}
                                </TableCell>
                                );
                            })}
                            </TableRow>
                        );
                        })}
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
            </TableContainer>
            <TablePagination
                rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 15]}
                component="div"
                count={rows.length}
                rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
                page={page}
                onChangePage={handleChangePage}
                onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
            />
        </Paper>

        </>
    )
}

export default FilesTable;
```

Comment: It seems odd for `DeleteFile` to be a separate component, rather than something that `FilesTable` handles.

Answer (score 1):

Typically with React you do this by **lifting state up** as described in [this React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

In this case, you'd lift the state to the parent of these components, and have the `FilesTable` receive the list of files as a prop. (Props are basically component state managed by the parent rather than by the component itself.) Similarly the `DeleteFile` component would receive the function to call to delete a file, the `UploadFile` component would receive the function to use to add a file, etc.

Here's a simplified example:

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Parent = () => {
    const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

    const addFile = (file) => {
        setFiles(files => [...files, file]);
    };

    const removeFile = (file) => {
        setFiles(files => files.filter(f => f !== file));
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <FilesTable files={files} removeFile={removeFile} />
            <UploadFile addFile={addFile} />
        </div>
    );
};

const FilesTable = ({files, removeFile}) => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div>{files.length === 1 ? "One file:" : `${files.length} files:`}</div>
            <ul className="files-table">
                {files.map(file => (
                    <li>
                        <span>{file}</span>
                        <span className="remove-file" onClick={() => removeFile(file)}>[X]</span>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

const UploadFile = ({addFile}) => {
    const [file, setFile] = useState("");

    const onClick = () => {
        addFile(file);
        setFile("");
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" value={file} onChange={(e) => setFile(e.target.value)} />
            <input type="button" value="Add" disabled={!file} onClick={onClick} />
        </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
ul.files-table {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.remove-file {
    margin-left: 0.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do not sure how to fit this into my current code (using Sweetalert file upload and useEffect

Comment: @IdanGonen - The above is an **example**, not a replacement. It demonstrates the kind of changes to make, where to keep the state and where to trigger the actions.